# How to return indices of a specific value from a matrix (Mat) in C++?

Tags: c++, opencv, matrix, return, return-value

How to return indices of a specific value in a 2d array?

this is what I have done until now:

```
Mat *SubResult;

for(int i=0; i < height; i++){
    for(int j=0; j< width; j++){
       if(SubResult[i][j]<0){
          return [i][j];
       }
    }
}
```

This is what I have done after your explanation but still I get error:

void Filter(float* currentframe, float* previousframe, float* SubResult){

```
int width ;
int height ; 
std::vector< std::pair< std::vector<int>, std::vector<int> > > Index;
cv::Mat curr = Mat(height, width, CV_32FC1, currentframe);
cv::Mat prev = Mat(height, width, CV_32FC1, previousframe);
//cv::Mat Sub = Mat(height, width, CV_32FC1, SubResult);
cvSub(currentframe, previousframe, SubResult);
cv::Mat Sub = Mat(height, width, CV_32FC1, SubResult);

for(int i=0; i < height; i++){
    for(int j=0; j< width; j++){
       if(Sub[i][j] < 0){
         Index.push_back(std::make_pair(i,j));
       }
     }

}
```

}
}

Answer (score 3):

Use [`pair<int,int>`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/utility/pair/) as your return type, and return a pair like this:

```
return make_pair(i, j);
```

On the receiving end the caller would need to access the elements of the pair as follows:

```
pair<int,int> p = find_2d(.....); // <<== Call your function
cout << "Found the value at (" << p.first << ", " << p.second << ")" << endl;
```

Comment: I want to show you what I have done after your explanation but stackoverflow does not let!! :(

Comment: @user2758510 Why did you make `Index` a vector of pairs of vectors? It looks like a `vector<pairs<int,int> >` should have worked fine as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can return it as a struct:

```
struct Index
{
   std::size_t i, j;
};

return Index{i, j};
```

Another way is `std::pair`:

```
return std::make_pair(i, j);
```

Answer (score 0):

To make sure that your function will work with existing and valid instance of `Mat`, pass by reference (since it will not change the matrix, make it `const`). Then you could return an `std::pair` or just simply fill the arguments that were passed by reference and return `bool` indicating a success:

```
bool foo(const Mat& img, int& x, int& y) {
    for(int i = 0; i < img.rows; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < img.cols; j++) {
           if(img[i][j] < 0) {
              x = j;
              y = i;
              return true;
           }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```